# 3rd Probability Axiom: Where did I go wrong?

Tags: probability

Today in class we're starting probability, and we went over three axioms of probability, which coincide with those here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms

The third axiom states: For a countable set of events $A_1, A_2, A_3, \ldots$, which are all disjoint:
$$P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \ldots) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) + P(A_3) + \ldots$$

I thought I had found a counter-example, but since this seems to be pretty darn well accepted, I know I'm wrong somewhere.

Say I choose a positive integer. Let $A_n$ be the event that I picked $n$. Clearly the left-hand side is 1, but $\forall n ~ P(A_n) = 0$ (almost never), so the right-hand side should be 0, I think.

What's the catch?

Comment: I know this is an old post, however, I wanted to add a potential nugget. We can construct a distribution such that the probability of each $A_n$ is as small as we like (but still positive), but never identically zero for all events. So you can make the probability of each event *effectively zero*, i.e. essentially zero according to human perception (and even beyond the capability of any finite-precision computer). It will "look like" each event is equally likely with probability zero. This is interesting philosophically but not mathematically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a catch, *per se*; the conclusion is simply that there *does not exist any* probability measure $P$ on the positive integers that is "uniform", i.e. such that $P(\text{choosing }n)$ is equal for all $n$, for precisely the reason you observed (I believe you are implicitly assuming this to be the case).

Suppose that $P$ were a probability measure on $\mathbb{N}$ (the positive integers) such that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $$P(\{n\})=\alpha$$
for some constant $\alpha$. If $\alpha>0$, then because $P$ is countably additive, we have
$$P(\mathbb{N})=P(\{1\})+P(\{2\})+\cdots=\alpha+\alpha+\cdots=\infty,$$
but this is not equal to $1$; but if $\alpha=0$, then similarly we conclude that $P(\mathbb{N})=0$, which is also a problem. Thus such a $P$ cannot exist.

---

However, there very well **can** exist probability measures on $\mathbb{N}$ that are *not* uniform. A standard example is the measure $P$ defined by
$$P(\{n\})=\frac{1}{2^n}.$$
Then we have
$$P(\mathbb{N})=P(\{1\})+P(\{2\})+\cdots=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots=1$$
and all is well. With this $P$, it is not true that $P(A_n)=0$ for all $n$, so the reasoning you followed leading to a contradiction doesn't apply.

Comment: Your answer clearly identifies the essence of the problem. However, the countable additivity axiom does not reference uniform distributions.

Comment: That's true, though I mentioned it because I thought it was implicit in the assumptions of the OP. I'll add some more to my answer to address it.

Comment: My formal probability knowledge is pretty slim, so just to check if I'm understanding right: there's no 'method' to uniformly select a random natural number, so I just started with something impossible?

Comment: @Henry: Yup, that's right. Assuming you're the Henry Swason who was my student at PROMYS, how's everything going?

Comment: Yep, same Henry. It's going pretty well. Got accepted to Caltech, so I can finally relax about college apps. Hopefully coming back to PROMYS this summer too (the Wavelet class looks especially interesting). And you?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are mistaking two things.

1. The $P(A_n) = 0$ is not quite correct, as $P(A_n) \gt 0$ for at least some of the n.
2. $\sum P(A_N) \ne 0$ as it is an infinite sum, and by other axioms of probability all $P(A_n) \ge 0$ such that $\sum P(A_N) = 1$ else the defined probabilities are not actually a probability distribution.

Edit to clarify: It may help to think of it this way.

Suppose $P(A_n) = 0$ for all n. Then by the rule of compliments, the $P(A_n^c) = 1 - P(A_n) = 1 - 0 = 1$, which implies that $P(A_j) \ne 0$ for some $j\ne n$, a contradiction to your original assumption